# Charge density relaxation, where does the charge go?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

I have read that the charge distribution in conducting medium will redistribute to the boundary and cancel out the electric field inside the medium. According to my understanding, This occurs because the conductor obeys the Ohm's law.

$\vec{J} = \sigma\vec{E}$

The dynamics process should stop when electric field is vanished.
assume that the medium is homogeneous and isotropic, applied Ohm's law to the continuity equation

$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{J}=0$

$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \sigma \vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{E} = 0$

$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}\rho = 0$

$\rho = \rho_0 \exp(\frac{-t}{\epsilon/\sigma})$

it is seem to me that the charge density just decays overtime and disappear but not redistributes to the medium boundary.

The question is where the charge goes?

Comment: How is the boundary defined? You could define it by a sharp change in sigma. But then you cannot take sigma out from the divergence. Akternativwly you could introduce terms for surface charges.